# How can I set and send a language on a device with Speechsynthezier? (Windows.Media.Speechsynthesis)

Tags: c#, uwp, speechsynthesizer

I'm a noob when it comes to programming, but I would like to make a Language Request-Handler where I get an array (Syntax: say language text), split it up,set the device language on the language give to me and let the device speak the text given. I couldn't really find anything about setting a language on a device.

I'm doing an UWP-Project, so I can only use the Windows.Media.Speechsynthezier.

This is my (unfinished!) code at the moment:

//public class LanguageRequestHandler

```
    string _request;
    SpeechSynthesizer synth;
    private SpeechSynthesizer _synth;



    public LanguageRequestHandler( string request)
    {
        _request = request;
        _synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        var voice = SpeechSynthesizer.AllVoices.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Gender == VoiceGender.Female) ?? SpeechSynthesizer.DefaultVoice;
        _synth.Voice = voice;

    }
```

//That should be only a check if the command send to me has the right invocation

```
    public string GetResponse()
    {

        string response = "invalid command";
        string[] args = _request.Split(' ');
        if (args[0] == "say")
        {
            response = CheckLanguage(args[1]);
        }

        return response;
    }
```

//Here I want to check what language is requested and I actually wanted to set the langauge the device should speak (but as you know by it looks, it is unfinished)

```
    public string CheckLanguage(string language)
    {
        string response = "No language selected";

        string[] args = _request.Split(' ');


        if (language == "spanish")
        {

        }
        else if(language == "english")
        {

        }
        else if (language == "german")
        {

        }
        else if (language == "french")
        {

        }

        return language;
    }
```

//Here I'm splitting the Text give to me and putting it together to a sentence that should be later on translated

```
    public string Text(string text)
    {
        string response = "No text given to translate";
        string[] args = _request.Split(' ');

        for (int i = 2; i < args.Length; i++)
        {
            response += args[i] + " ";

        }

        return text;
    }
```

//Lastly I'm trying to set the volume of the device and synthesis from text to speech which should be streamed to the device and let it speak

```
    public async void Talk(string message)
    {
        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer { Volume = 100 };

        var stream = await _synth.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(message);
        mp.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromStream(stream, stream.ContentType);
        mp.Play();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could open the **'Windows Settings -> Time& Language -> Language -> Add a language -> Select one language and click the Options button -> Click the Download button below the Speech'**.

[image]

After that, go to the **Speech** on the left menus and set the speech language.

[image]

Comment: I have already done that, still thank you for that. I think I have written my question poorly, but I want to send a request on a device that can change the devices  language already installed on it (from german to english, english to spanish etc.)

Comment: @CookieMax There's no APIs for you to directly change the device language. You could only [Launch the Windows Settings app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-settings-app) to let the user to change it in windows settings.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I need to add the Language.Contains()Function to set or change a language. It should be noted that you need to insert a BCP47 Code for the desired language (Example:
i.Language.Contains("fr-FR") for French)

"var voice = SpeechSynthesizer.AllVoices.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Gender == VoiceGender.Female && **i.Language.Contains(_request)**) ?? SpeechSynthesizer.DefaultVoice;"

Since I found a solution to this problem, I somehow need to split the _request given to me (since the syntax is "say  ") and just give it the the BCP47 Code in it (thats why I made the method Checklanguage, it should take it out of the array and put the code in it)